# Does @WebMvcTest require @SpringBootApplication annotation?

Tags: spring-boot

My goal is to migrate a Spring Boot application previously developed with Spring Boot 1.3 to the newest Spring Boot version 1.4. The application consists of several maven modules and only one of them contains class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

One part of migration is to use `@WebMvcTest` annotation to efficiently test controllers, and here I get an issue.

Consider an [example application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-test) from Spring Boot github page. `@WebMvcTest` annotation works perfectly, because, as far as I understand (after I did several tests), there is a class in the main package annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. Note that I follow the same concept as shown in the example above for my own `@WebMvcTest` tests.

The only difference I see that in my application, controller classes are located in a separate maven module (without `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class), but with @Configuration and `SpringBootConfiguration` configurations. If I do not annotate any class with `@SpringBootApplication` I always get an assertion while testing controller. My assertion is the same as when SampleTestApplication class in the example above modified to have only `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotations (`@SpringBootApplication` is not present):

```
getVehicleWhenRequestingTextShouldReturnMakeAndModel(sample.test.web.UserVehicleControllerTests)  Time elapsed: 0.013 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$10.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:664)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
   at sample.test.web.UserVehicleControllerTests.getVehicleWhenRequestingTextShouldReturnMakeAndModel(UserVehicleControllerTests.java:68)
```

How should I deal with that? Should I always have class annotated with @SpringBootApplication in order to run @WebMvcTest tests?

EDIT 1: I did a small maven project with 2 modules and a minimal configuration. It is [here](https://github.com/tysonite/webmvc-test). Now, I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException exception for repository defined in another module. If I configure "full" @SpringBootApplication - everything is fine.

EDIT 2: I modified small test project from EDIT 1 to give an original issue. I was playing with different annotations and added @ComponentScan on configuration class, because I suspected that beans are not registered properly. However, I expect that only @Controller bean (defined in @WebMvcTest(...class)) shall be registered based on magic behind @WebMvcTest behaviour.

EDIT 3: Spring Boot project [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6633).

Comment: I got your small project to pass the test. Not sure if that is enough to answer your question or if you need to move some classes around to better represent the problem.

Comment: @ShawnClark, thanks for trying. You added `@SpringBootApplication` to the configuration class. May be, I was not completely clear before, but this trick also works for me. I expect that in my module I do not need to put  `@SpringBootApplication`.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: I believe so.

Long answer:

I believe `@WebMvcTest` needs to find the SpringBootApplication configuration since `WebMvcTest`'s sole purpose is to help simplify tests (`SpringBootApplication` would rather try to load the whole world).

In your specific case, since you don't have any in your non-test packages, I believe it also finds SampleTestConfiguration which is annotated with `@ScanPackages` and somehow loads every beans.

Add the following in `src/main/java/sample/test`

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleTestConfiguration {

}
```

And change your test to this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private MyService ms;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void getDataAndExpectOkStatus() throws Exception {
        given(ms.execute("1")).willReturn(false);
        mvc.perform(get("/1/data").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("false"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyControllerInAppCtx() {
        assertThat(context.getBean(MyController.class), is(not(nullValue())));
    }

    @Test
    public void testNoMyAnotherControllerInAppCtx() {
        try {
            context.getBean(MyAnotherController.class);
            fail("Bean exists");
        } catch (BeansException e) {
            // ok
        }
    }
}
```

`@WebMvcTest` finds the `SpringBootApplication`, then load **only a limited number of beans** (see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests)):

> @WebMvcTest will auto-configure the Spring MVC infrastructure and
> limit scanned beans to @Controller, @ControllerAdvice, @JsonComponent,
> Filter, WebMvcConfigurer and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver. Regular
> @Component beans will not be scanned when using this annotation.

`WebMvcTest` requires `SpringBootApplication`: `WebMvcTest` inherits many AutoConfiguration, so it needs SpringBoot to load them. Then it disables many other AutoConfiguration and your Controllers become easily testable.

**The whole point of using `WebMvcTest` is when you have a `SpringBootApplication` and you wish to make it simpler to test by disabling all beans except Controllers. If you don't have SpringBootApplication, then why use WebMvcTest at all?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes,according to the [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config)

> The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class. As long as you’ve structure your code in a sensible way your main configuration is usually found.

But after I started using `@WebMvcTest`,spring boot still try to load other beans, finally `TypeExcludeFilter` did the trick.

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = {JzYsController.class} )
    public class JzYsControllerTest {

        private static final String REST_V4_JZYS = "/rest/v4/JzYs";

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @MockBean
        private JzYsService service;

        @Test
        public void deleteYsByMlbh() throws Exception {
            Mockito.when(service.deleteYsByMlbh(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.of(1));
            mockMvc.perform(delete(REST_V4_JZYS + "?mbbh=861FA4B0E40F5C7FECAF09C150BF3B01"))
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
        }

        @SpringBootConfiguration
        @ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class))
        public static class config{
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's an old topic, but there is a solution which wasn't mentioned here.

You can create a class annotated with `SpringBootApplication` just in your test sources. Then, you still have a nice, multi-module structure of your project, with just one "real" `SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: You need to annotate you class with @ContextConfiguration(classes = TestSpringBootApplication.class) in order to specify custom @SpringBootApplication for test.

Comment: Thanks @EugeneMaysyuk .This helped

Answer (score 0):

There is one more solution. You can not use @WebMvcTest, but configure MockMvc yourself through the builder

```java
class TestControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new TestController())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {

        // When
        var res = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test/test"));

        // Then
        res.andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

But this solution may entail a number of other problems, such as problems with configurations, environment property injections, etc.